# C++ Text File Translation to Vector

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and currently, I have written a function that puts the contents of a text file into a vector.

```
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > sprites;
        std::ifstream file("initialroom.txt");
        std::string line;

        for (line; std::getline(file, line);){
            sprites.push_back(std::vector<int>());
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(sprites.back()));
        }
```

```
initialroom.txt:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 3 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

While this does work, I want it to use this text file instead

initialroomdesired.txt:

```
# # # # # # # # # #
# . . . . . . . . # 
# . & . . . . # . #
# . & . . . . # . # 
# . . . . $ . # # #
# . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . #
# . & & . . . . . # 
# . . . . . . . . # 
# # # # # # # # # #
```

and depending on the symbol that is being shown, it corresponds it to a number instead (# = 0, . = 1, & = 2, $ = 3), so it looks like initialroom.txt in the vector that it will be stored in.

My issue at the moment, is that I cannot wrap my head around how I would go about doing this.

I tried making switch statements for the stringstream, but I was thrown errors in regards to pointers.

Comment: Load the file as you already do, but into a matrix of *characters*. Then iterate over all the cells in the character matrix, and translate the characters to the corresponding integer value and store it in your `sprite` matrix.

Comment: Show what you tried with the switch statement (enough code and invokation info to be able to reproduce the error). I'd suggest you try to break the problem into two. Try to either tackle just the border characters or just the character-mapping-to-ints first.